# Passwording an external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, security, encryption

Was wondering if there is a way to protect the contents of an external hard drive?

Is it possible to password an external hard drive, such that when its plugged to a system, a password will be required to access it?

Comment: http://www.truecrypt.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.org) can do this. You'll want to encrypt the entire drive as seen in the second option here **"Encrypt a non-system partition/drive"**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be better on SuperUser or ServerFault. Directly I do not know of any way to do this, it might be better to know what O/S you are trying to accomplish this under. You could use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) or something similar to encrypt the disk at the volume level. However with TrueCrypt it would not prompt you for the password necessarily, it would just show the drive as full of white noise (i.e. unformatted), you would have to know to load the driver for mounting the volume and provide the appropriate password.

It should also be noted that TrueCrypt (and BitLocker as well) have been shown to have a flaw which does allow someone to intercept the loading of the secure driver and pre-empt the password verification routine giving them access to the password. This attack is non-trivial to accomplish and does require physical access to the device. You can read about the [Evil Maid](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2009/10/evil-maid-goes-after-truecrypt.html) attack here.

Answer (score 0):

**DiskCryptor - open source partition encryption solution**

> **[DiskCryptor](http://diskcryptor.net/index.php/DiskCryptor_en)** is the only truly free solution, provided under GNU
>   General Public License (GPLv3), which
>   offers encryption of all disk
>   partitions, including the system
>   partition. The main criteria for
>   open-source software is the
>   availability of its source code under
>   one of the open source licenses. The
>   only open-source alternative to
>   DiskCryptor that has comparable
>   features is TrueCrypt. However,
>   because of the restrictive license
>   under which TrueCrypt is provided -
>   the TrueCrypt Collective License -
>   TrueCrypt cannot be classified as a
>   truly free software, as it places
>   limits on the use and modification of
>   its source code by developers. There
>   are other alternatives with similar
>   functionality, but they are fully
>   proprietary ones, which makes them
>   unacceptable to use for protection of
>   confidential data.

as with all encrypted drives (and especially portable drives), you should keep a backup of your files in a safe location (possibly unencrypted)!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, [LUKS](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) is included with most Linux distributions these days.  You can use LUKS to encrypt an external hard disk, USB stick, you name it, as well.

If you are worried about needing access from Windows, you can use [FreeOTFE](http://www.freeotfe.org/) to access LUKS encrypted drives.